# What are the differences between private and protected visibility modifiers in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, access-modifiers

I just started to learn the kotlin and got confused with the protected access modifier my doubt is what is the exact differences between private and protected access modifier in kotlin. I have searched on the google but didn't get any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Same as in Java

Comment: [kotlin reference # visibility modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) probably contains everything you need to know... if not, then please be more specific...

Comment: @AntonA. this is not correct. see my answer.

Comment: @homerman and what is different from Java??

Comment: @AntonA. Java doesn't support `private` for top-level declarations.

Comment: @AntonA. also in java protected includes package-local, in Kotlin it doensn't

Answer (score 4):

As in most OOP languages there are several modifiers in Kotlin:

`public` - class, function or property can be reached from anywhere in the project.
In Kotlin by default the class, property or function are public

`protected` - class, function or property can be reached only by the current class subclasses

`private` - class, function or property can be reached only in the current class

`internal` - class, function or property can be reached from anywhere in the current module

Comment: It's also worth noting that when calling Kotlin functions from Java code, the modifiers will act in the Java way. for example, when declaring a `protected` function in Kotlin, then it can be called from Java code in the same package, as if it had been declared `protected` in Java (but can't be called from Kotlin code in the same package unless it's also a subclass)

Answer (score 1):

As official [documentatin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) says:

> `private` means visible inside this class only (including all its
>   members);
>
> `protected` — same as `private` + visible in subclasses too;

Answer (score 0):

From [Kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces):

> private — means visible inside this class only (including all its members);
>
> protected — same as private + visible in subclasses too;

By visible, it means the field or method can be accessed or used.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) for detailed description.

If you want to understand the protected concept you need a basic understanding of subclasses and inheritance.

Variables or Functions with protected access specifier can be seen from child classes. But private will binds the scope within the class.

consider this basic code:

```
    open class Outer {
        private val a = 1 // visible only for instance of class Outer
        protected open val b = 2 // visible for instance of Outer and another subclass which inherits Outer.
        val d = 4  // public by default
        protected class Nested {
            public val e: Int = 5
        }
    }

    public class Subclass : Outer() {
        // a is not visible
        // b, d are visible
        // Nested and e are visible

        override val b = 5   // 'b' is protected
    }
```

Note: The above code is from docs.

Answer (score 0):

#### As it relates to class members:

- items marked `protected` are visible within the class and subclasses
- items marked `private` are visible within the class

#### As it relates to top-level declarations:

- (`protected` is not applicable)
- items marked `private` are visible within the same file